# How to convert Class name ActiveRecord::Result to ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem with my SQL query trying to download it on CSV format.

**I know about SQL injection but for now, this is all I have**

So I have this SQL query. payment_report or result is posted on the view. I pass the result query to `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query()` and gives me the result I wanted, the problem comes when trying to download this as CSV.

```
sql = "SELECT

        payments.response_code as transaction_id,
        orders."'number'" || '-' || payments."'number'" as invoice_number,
        orders.user_id,
        orders.email,
        variants.sku,
        line_items.price,
        orders.item_total,
        orders.total,
        payments.created_at,
        payments.updated_at

        FROM

        public.spree_payments,
        public.spree_orders,
        public.spree_line_items,
        public.spree_variants

        WHERE

        payments.order_id = orders.id AND
        orders.id = line_items.order_id AND
        line_items.variant_id = variants.id AND
        payments.state = 'completed' AND
        orders.completed_at BETWEEN SYMMETRIC
        '#{params[:q][:created_at_gt]}' AND '#{params[:q][:created_at_lt]}'
        "
```

`@payment_report = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)`

I have this code to download my a CSV format.
`reports_controller.rb`

```
respond_with(@payment_report) do |format|
          format.csv do
            send_data @payment_report.to_payment_report_csv,
                      filename: "Payment Report - #{params[:q][:created_at_gt].to_date} to #{params[:q][:created_at_lt].to_date}.csv"
          end
```

I have this on code on my model
`payment.rb`

```
def self.to_payment_report_csv
      col_names = %w[
        transaction_id
        number
        user_id
        email
        sku
        price
        item_total
        total
        created_at
        updated_at
      ]

      CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << col_names
        all.each do |pay|
          row = []

          row << pay.transaction_id
          row << pay.number
          # row << pay.user.id
          # row << pay.email
          # row << pay.sku
          # row << pay.price
          # row << pay.item_total
          # row << pay.total
          row << pay.created_at
          row << pay.updated_at

          csv << row
        end
      end
    end
```

but I tried to click the button and download I get this error.

`undefined method to_payment_report_csv for #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x00007f3faf4c8ad8>`

my conclusion is that upon checking on my payment model it has an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that's why I wanted to convert it.

I'm doing the raw SQL because the condition is preventing me from using ActiveRecord. Also, I'm supposed to use ransack but again the condition is preventing me to use ransack. So the ransack form is just used to get the dates. I also think because of my schema.

```
Orders:
   has_may: :Line_items, :Payments, Variants
```

```
LineItem:
   belongs_to: :Variant, :Order
```

```
Payment
   belongs_to: Order
```

`Variant doesn't relate to anything`

**UPDATE**
for some reason this is working.

```
Spree::Order.ransack(orders_gt: params[:q][:created_at_gt], orders_lt:
params[:q][:created_at_lt], payments_order_id_in: [Spree::Order.ids],
payments_state_eq: 'completed', orders_id_in: [Spree::LineItem.all.pluck(:order_id)]).result.includes(:payments, :line_items, :variants).joins(:line_items, :payments, :variants).to_json
```

but if I added this one.
`line_items_variant_id_in: [Spree::Variant.ids]` i get and error of

```
undefined method `to_i' for #<Array:0x00007fbd991fd7c8>
```

I didnt even put `to_i` any where. hmmm. any idea?

Comment: I'm looking for a different way of solving it btw. may be I could make this work using ransack.

Comment: There is no simple way to convert it the results from a raw SQL query into an ActiveRecord::Relation. ActiveRecord does quite a lot of work trying to figure out where to put all that data it fetches from the database. You will have to start figuring out how to perform the query with AR's query interface. I don't really think this question is on topic as its way too broad.

Comment: @max Thank for the information. Yes I found the way. I manage to use the ransack. Can you give me insight or comment about the way I solved it?

Comment: I'll post an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figure it out. I don't know If its the right way though so I have this query using ransack.

```
@payment_report = Spree::Order.ransack(
          orders_gt: params[:q][:created_at_gt],
          orders_lt: params[:q][:created_at_lt],
          payments_order_id_in: [Spree::Order.ids],
          payments_state_eq: 'completed',
          orders_id_in: [Spree::LineItem.all.pluck(:order_id)],
          variants_id_in: [Spree::LineItem.ids]
        ).result.includes(:payments, :line_items, :variants).joins(:line_items, :payments, :variants)
```

apparently, you can do multiple queries on ransack but it wasn't there on their documentation I found the answer on bug report on their GitHub. yea so for now I have this. but the raw query is different from here. so still have a problem